# Как сделать автоматическое обновление загруженного контента при создании/редактировании записи, без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: php, wordpress

Я вывожу таблицу записей, хочу сделать автоматическое обновление этой таблицы при создании или редактировании записи. Искал информацию, самое адекватное, что нашел - ajax подгрузка по таймеру, можно ли сделать так, чтобы при срабатывании хука создания/редактирования срабатывала ajax подгрузка?

Comment: Обычно - нет. Сервер не может инициировать запрос к браузеру пользователя на обновление страницы. Вам надо подключать websocket или же делать то, что вы уже нашли - ajax по таймеру с запросом, было ли обновление страницы и если да, то вывод обновленния на экран. Кстати, именно так работает WP в админке, актуализируя редактируемый пост. Есть специальный скрипт heartbeat для этих целей.

Comment: А, так вы хотите как раз при редактировании обновлять? Ну ок, надо вешать ваш код обновления на событие heartbeat.

Comment: @KAGGDesign понял, спасибо